# Showing Html in WinRT with RichTextBlock or other component

Tags: c#, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, converters

I want to show html in string with some component. Now I am using RichTextBlock and I tried few extensions for converting html to xaml or rtf but I didn´t found any working with WinRT. I know I can use WebView but it isn´t so pretty. I just want to do little change to `ItemDetailPage` (where is used RichTextBlock) to show users elementary html (bold, italics, links, images, ...).

Is there some component or some way how to do this (not webview)? Or is there working convertor?

Comment: how about doing view source in the web control?

Comment: You would have to build your own parser.  It sounds like you are barking up the wrong tree if you have to do that.

Comment: Could you provide more detail why the WebView (which is IE10) isn't the best component for showing HTML?

Comment: I like how RTB is looking in default ItemDetailPage. Text is in columns a user is moving with text horizontally.

Comment: Component library has that richtextbox which I found very good and easy to use, but it is too much expensive for me, sharing this for those who can afford. I have tried its trial version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 ways

1. build or get your own html to xaml parser to use the contents as RichTextBox Source
2. Use WebView to display html content

I recommend WebView because this componente have a lot of features that is very difficult to implement as a parser

- javascript support
- css support
- bad formed (real world) html support
- etc

So, in a WebView control you can use WebView.NavigateToString method to display html contents stored in a string.

Yo can, even, modify string to changes styles, add scripts, etc as you need to custom webview look and feel.

NavigateToString has no support for binding but I wrote an article (spanish) teaching how to doing using attached properties: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/juank/archive/2012/10/29/tutorial-crear-app-lector-rss-winrt-parte-7.aspx

**Use this code(plex) to  parsing**, if it not fit exactly you can change te code for your own. ;) http://html2xaml.codeplex.com/

Other wise you would create the ode yourself, if you want break pages in column text (to horizontal reading) you must use RichTextBlock, use RichTextColumns hepler class ( included in Common/ folder when you start your app from a template) and try to parse HTML to XAML.

Comment: I tried WebView and I found an article how to binding myself and it works, html look good. But I don´t want to use it because I want to show mainly text with html tags. It would be basic tags like bold, italics, lists and sometimes images and links. It should show articles so long text and I like that view of RichTextBlock in sample page (ItemDetailPage). Text is in columns and user is moving with it horizontally. I don´t know how to do it with WebView.

Comment: If you want break pages in column text (to horizontal reading) you must use RichTextBlock, use RichTextColumns hepler class included in Common/ folder when you start your app from a template and try to parse HTML to XAML. Use this code(plex) to  parsing, if it not fit exactly you can change te code for your own. ;) http://html2xaml.codeplex.com/  I have added this part to the answer.

Comment: how would you pass the xaml that is generated by html2xaml to the RichTextBlock? I passed my html to html2xaml via a converter and it works great except it returns the actual XAML I want to render, so the actual XAML text is what I see in the RichtTextBlock! How can I show this XAML instead of using it as the Text value?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got fed up with the lack of WinRT-supported Html to Xaml conversion and wrote my own. For kicks, I put it on [codeplex](http://winrthtml2xaml.codeplex.com/). For even further kicks, and to experiment with NuGet, I published it there, too...

Obviously, this isn't the end-all of Html to Xaml conversion, but it's a start...

Comment: Did u forget to add some test app that shows it in action. It's kind of useless without it for anybody to try it quickly.

Comment: There should be enough at the codeplex site to get you most of the way there. If you have questions, there's also the Issue Tracker or the Discussions tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a library which parses HTML and renders the HTML using native controls. The component is very flexible and extensible.

Have a look at:

- http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HtmlTextBlock