# Windows Store: Disable webView zoom

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Zooming is turned on by default in a `WebView` Element in Windows Store 8/8.1 Apps. How can you disable zooming in a `WebView`? I don't want users on any device (especially touch devices) to zoom in and out of a `WebView`. I am using c# as the programming language.

Answer (score -2):

You can't disable zoom in webview for windows store apps. AFAIK it is still won't work for windows 8.1

from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c1181cc0-ead1-4665-8cfb-9b2aba7d3e6f/how-to-disable-webview-control-vertical-scroll-bar-in-windows-81?forum=w81prevwCsharp). But you can handle(resize the content) zoom of webview if you want. Look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/05/28/webview-magic-tricks-zoom-levels.aspx)

Try this [Sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-41-94-21/WebViewZoom.zip)

I believe they are using this in IE 10 [Link](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/10337-internet-explorer-modern-zoom-level-change.html).

**Edit :**

You can use [RichTextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227565) to display HTML string.

More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088034/showing-html-in-winrt-with-richtextblock-or-other-component) & [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/72a2b207-13d8-4ddc-868a-fafbc07d283b/how-to-convert-html-content-in-richtextbox-for-win8-app?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Hope this helpful

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I suspected. It really doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @user1954801 U didn't mention what you are loading in webview. By knowing this we can any find alternative remedy for this.

Comment: I am loading a custom html-string.

Comment: Pretty hacky solution I assume (parsing html..). With inline JavaScript and CSS, this seems to be a dead end. +1 for your effort!

Comment: The link is down for the sample. Posting links isnt an answer